# Need to delete old SKU# and enter new SKU # onto a master sheet

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

This project keeps throwing new and exciting things that I am having a good deal of trouble with.

I am hoping that there is an easy solution but I am starting to suspect it may be a macro problem.

What I have is...a master list of products, 10,000 of them.  It is now end of season and we are moving a range of products to a discontinued section.

So what I need to know is how can I delete all the SKU's I need to...and then as an added bonus feature...add the NEW SKU's for this season into the master list.

What I am hoping to do is create something that when we have to do this again in six months...we dont have to enter the data individually and just add a discontinued list...and a new list and it will auto update the main list.

I will have to add SKUS and the data they contain and my only knowledge of this is using Vlookup.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is far too broad to yield helpful specific answers to individual programming challenges, which is SO's main target.  When you develop more specific steps and try to implement them, you'll be able to take better advantage of this site.  In general, I'd advise you to step back and do some longer-range thinking about the various tasks you'll need to do with these 10,000 products over the next year or two and get somebody with retail database experience to help you design something that will work for the long term.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to tackle this, but you haven't given enough info to get a specific answer.

For example, if you have that list of discontinued product numbers somewhere, you could easily run a vlookup formula against that data source to the master data source.  Then, just sort out the stuff you want and delete it or move it or whatever.

It also begs the question of why you have a 'discontinued' section.  I loathe 'sections' in a database.  If it's a real DB table, there shouldn't be any breaks anywhere....you'd deal with 'discontinued' versus 'active' with an additional field (column) and mark things as such there.

If the table and the data is organized well, you can easily do these tasks you are talkign about.

Comment: thanks Kevin, I thought I could find a pice I was missing, but I have to do it like you have suggested. I have made the sheet tell me the products that are discontinued and I then change them manually...which is probably for the best.